# Connecting Redis Cache with AKS cluster

Tags: azure-aks, azure-redis-cache

I'm trying to host a couple of micro services in AKS. There is some data stored in a Azure-redis cache in a separate virtual network which the AKS cluster needs to access. Do I need to use [OSBA for Azure](https://github.com/Azure/open-service-broker-azure) to enable this connection? or can I just configure the access url for redis and configure external routes to the Redis from AKS.

I am confused because my Redis is in a separate virtual network and the AKS is deployed in a separate virtual network.

Comment: You can set the connection which you can access from the Internet. Or you can use the vnet peering, then you can access the Redis from the vnet.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. Our Redis and AKS clusters were in different geo-locations and in different VNETs.

You can connect these 2 VNETS with VNET Peering. This acts as a bridge between these 2 VNETs.

The official documentation for this is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Comment: Please add relevant information into the answer from the given doc than just giving the link.